# Alterar atributo Text de um linkbutton dentro de uma table em um repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho esse linkbutton:

```
<td><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbEnviarDocumentos" CssClass="acessos" Text="Documentos" runat="server" /></td>} %>
```

Quando essa condição for verdadeira `if(hdfTipoUsuario.Value == "2")` tenho que alterar o Text de

> Documentos

para

> Validar Documentos

Como eu faço isso?
Já tentei assim:

```
(LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lkbEnviarDocumentos").Text
```

mas dessa forma não funciona. Dessa outra forma também não. `lkbEnviarDocumentos.Text = "Validar Documentos";`
Qual a forma correta de fazer isso? Tentei no Asp.Net, colocando um IF lá, mas ele não aceitou, ele disse que há dois ID's iguais, ou seja, não considerou no if ou esse ou aquele, dessa forma.

```
<% if(hdfTipoUsuario.Value != "2"){%>
                        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbEnviarDocumentos" CssClass="acessos" Text="Documentos" runat="server" /></td>} %>
                        <% } 
                        else
                        {%>
                        <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbEnviarDocumentos" CssClass="acessos" Text="Validar Documentos" runat="server" /></td>
                        <% } %>
```

Quase me esqueço: Tudo isso está dentro do `itemcommand` do `repeater`.

Entendendo bem, acho que o itemcommand não é lugar para isso, certo?

Fiz esse DataBound e agora dá erro, dizendo: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
protected void rptBens_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            //Declarações
            LinkButton vlkbDocumentos = null;

            //Instâncias e Inicializações
            vlkbDocumentos = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lkbEnviarDocumentos");

            //Desenvolvimento
            if (vlkbDocumentos.Text != string.Empty)
            { 
                if (hdfTipoUsuario.Value == "2")
                {
                    vlkbDocumentos.Text = "Validar Documentos";
                }
            }

        }
```

Estava fazendo de forma errada, mas consertei. O if agora está assim e não dá mais erro:

```
if (vlkbDocumentos != null)
            { 
                if (hdfTipoUsuario.Value == "2")
                {
                    vlkbDocumentos.Text = "Validar Documentos";
                }
            }
```

Acontece que mesmo dessa forma, está acontecendo o seguinte: O botão vem repetido, um em cima do outro. Um com text `Documentos` e em baixo desse `Validar Documentos`, fazendo da forma acima citada.

Comment: Acho que deveria criar um evento ItemDataBound para o repeater e tratar lá, certo? No caso do IF no asp.net, os dois botões são carregados, pois ele exige dois botões(ID's diferentes).

Comment: Mesmo eu removendo do asp.net o text do linkbutton, ainda assim continua vindo errado. Em algum lugar ele preenche essa propriedade Text do linkbutton.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema. Em realidade meu IF está correto. Acontece que estava dentro de uma table, ele quebrou o layout e, sinceramente, parecia que havia dois botões. Como eswtava muito apertado, quando inspecionava, só marcava a parte de cima. Só descobri, quando o colega que é designer falou, para eu aumentar o width da  e foi quando percebi que era apenas um botão. Closed case.